# why post method is not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post data to a rest api and then show that data in the same page.
Here is the code for the form where i am adding the data

```
<div>
<form name="posts">
            <table class="table">

                <tr>
                   <td>
                        <input name="userId" type="text" ng-model="userId"/>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input name="id" type="text" ng-model="id"/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" />
                     </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="body" ng-model="body" />
                   </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" ng-click="AddNewPost()" />

                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
</div>
```

Here i am showing the added data

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>UserId</th>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Body</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody >
     <td>{{UserId}}</td>
     <td>{{Id}}</td>
     <td>{{Title}}</td>
     <td>{{Body}}</td>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
  </table>
```

and the controller method i have used is

```
 $scope.AddNewPost = function () {
               var pst = {
                   userId: $scope.userId,
                   id: $scope.id,
                   title: $scope.title,
                   body: $scope.body

               };
               $http({
                 method: 'POST',
                 url:'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
                 data: pst,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
              }).success(function(data){
               $scope.UserId=pst.userId;
                    $scope.Id=pst.id;
                    $scope.Title=pst.title;
                    $scope.Body=pst.body;
               });

           }
```

But it is not working . I know there are questions asked on this topic previously but they didn't help me. I am new to angular so please help me finding where am I making the mistake.

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya No , It just not showing the data

Comment: try console.log(data) in post success

Comment: as per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http this docs you can also add error callback function to check whats going wrong

Comment: Open dev tools -> network and see what exactly error is or look at the server response status code.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya  It shows  " Object { {"userId":"","id":"","title":"","body":""}: "", id: 101 }"

Comment: data will be encoded as JSON, not as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Comment: then it is working. what is problem?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya  If post is success then the same data should be shown in the lower section of the html ,which is not showing.

Comment: can you make fiddle or plunker so that i can debug there

Comment: `Object { {"userId":"","id":"","title":"","body":""}: "", id: 101 }"` where is your data? all of your properties (e.g-> Id, Title etc.) are empty. How data will be displayed?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya  Here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/shahzad285/bkUEu/2943/     but it is working fine there, don't know what is the issue when I am trying to use in my local system

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using same `pst` variable to assign value to scope variables. you must ensure first by checking `console.log`that `pst` is having values in it. 
you should do

> Assuming `data` returned form post contain `post` object

Change

```
.success(function(data){
               $scope.UserId=pst.userId;
                    $scope.Id=pst.id;
                    $scope.Title=pst.title;
                    $scope.Body=pst.body;
               });
```

To

```
 .success(function(data){
           $scope.UserId=data.post.userId;
                    $scope.Id=data.post.id;
                    $scope.Title=data.post.title;
                    $scope.Body=data.post.body;
               });
```

> I recomend for multiple post data you should use ng-repeat in your
>   HTML

Comment: he is  getting blank value in response and he want to show data from pst object

Answer (score 0):

```
 $http.post(url, dataObject, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {

        //success

      }, function(error) {
      //error
      });
```

Try this code.